# Refresh a UITabBar tab's view or call a method from the UITabBar tab's view when the tab is reselected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

Except for the first time a tab is switched-to, when the ViewDidLoad is initially triggered, all subsequent actions of switching to (reselecting) that tab doesn't seem to trigger ViewDidLoad, nor any other method. The view just seemed to be cached and reshown instantly, just the way it was left when the user switched away from that tab. However, when a particular tab gets reselected by the user, I need to refresh its view. Thus, if possible, I need to somehow trigger a method from within the view without additional user interaction (after the tab reselection).

I do know there's a method in the UITabBarDelegate that is supposed to get called before or after tab switching occurs, but I wouldn't know if that would be the way to go to trigger a method call from within the tab's view upon reactivation of said tab. I don't know how I'd access the already active instance of the tab's view from within the delegate. Any direction on this would be greatly helpful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using UITabBar, your views are kept alive unless a memory warning is received and they have to be deallocated.  Because they are kept perpetually alive, viewDidLoad will only be called once (unless your view is unloaded due to a memory warning).

viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear will be called each time that view will/did show on the screen, so this is where you'd want to refresh your view or data.

viewWillAppear is better to use in instances that you want to update anything on the view before it is seen by the user.  For instance, setting UILabels or UITextFields to clear data.  This would prevent the user from seeing a quick flash of the old data before it is cleared out.  Running anything in this method that will use significant system resources or take a long time (ie. webservices) may slow your app and will prevent you from showing the UIActivityIndicator simultaneously, as this is before the view actually appears.

viewDidAppear is useful for anything that can be updated after the view is already shown, such as webservices from the previous example.

Comment: Now I'm curious what the animated BOOL is for on those two methods. Anything special or hazardous I should make note of?

Comment: The animated BOOL is how you would indicate if there is an animation happening when that view appears.  Most transitions between views include an animation, so that the transition does not seem choppy.  It is more common to use no animation on the first view that is shown in the app when it first starts.

Comment: @superjessi. Is it ok to get web service response? I am using xml/soap and I want to refresh and filled data from webservice when I switch tab.

Answer (score 3):

I do the same in one of my app's and I use the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` to accomplish this.

They seem to be called every time the tab is re-selected. (I've created a method `updateView` that gets called inside the `viewDidAppear` method)

Comment: Aha! I must have confused the two.

Comment: @Faizan S. How do you call this method? Can you explain more. I want web-service called when I switching tabs.